# Open popup in content scripts(Chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, popup, content-script

I have a js file that should open the popup of the Chrome extension, so
how can I open the popup when the user clicks on some input element with jquery.

the js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input").focus(function(){ 
        //open popup
});
```

});

Comment: you can't. Popup may be opened only by user click on browser action (the extension icon)

Comment: so can I open some dialog?

Comment: Sure, you can open new tabs, windows or modal div on an page

Comment: Can you give me an example pls? the closest something to popup

Comment: Start creating a new tab. Read this docs https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/

Comment: There is something more likely popup, not a whole tab?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to automatically open a "popup", you should rather convert chromium's "Extension Popup" to just a "Extension Window" that looks like a popup.

For example (assuming Manifest v3):

In your **manifest.json**, don't specify the popup.

```
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "128": "icon.png"
    }
  }
```

Then in your **background.js**, listen when the user clicks on that popup, remember, in Manifest v3, background pages are just event pages, so all logic should run as if the closure is being run at that moment:

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(() => {
  chrome.windows.create({
    focused: true,
    width: 400,
    height: 600,
    type: 'popup',
    url: 'popup.html',
    top: 0,
    left: 0
  },
  () => {})
})
```

With some math, you can position that popup in the area you want by calling `window.screen`

Additionally, if you just want a single instance of that popup, you can query all the extension windows that are open to see if that popup is opened.

Comment: I couldn't find a good solution for the "Service worker registration failed" problem...

Comment: Add a try catch around your service worker, and you will get a reason why registration failed.